# Google Maps API v3: InfoWindow not sizing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

It appears my InfoWindow, when you click on the home icon on my Google Maps v3, is not properly auto-sizing to the content of the InfoWindow.

It gives scrollbars when it should not. The InfoWindow should be properly auto-sizing.

Any ideas on why?

Per request, the relevant JavaScript which injects the HTML for the InfoWindow:

```
listing = '<div>Content goes here</div>';
```

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled by Google in issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823659

The fix was implemented in February 2015 in version 3.19 of Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: better to copy the relevant code into your question. Otherwise this question becomes meaningless when the code on your site changes.

Comment: Well, that's the whole point actually. It's my understanding that the Google Maps v3 API is suppose to auto-size regardless of my CSS ... and it is not. But I'll post the code anyways

Comment: I know this is old, but in case someone gets here and tries everything and still has a problem (like I did):

The infowindows have a max height proportionate to your map dimensions. This is smaller than v2. So if you are upgrading from v2 to v3 and have this issue, it could be because of this. Either make your content shorter, or your map longer, or downgrade back to v2.

Answer (score 32):

Add a div inside your infowindow

```
<div id=\"mydiv\">YourContent</div>
```

Then set the size using css. works for me. This asumes all infowindows are the same size!

```
#mydiv{
width:500px;
height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Same size or you create enough classes in your css with different dimensions.

Comment: depending on how you are working with your infowindows, it might well be safer to use a class rather than an ID, to avoid duplicate IDs floating around on the same page, eg `<div class=\"mydiv\">YourContent</div>` and `.mydiv{
width:500px;
height:100px;
}`

Comment: It works on desktop, but not on mobile devices (Android)/

Answer (score 31):

Short answer: **set the maxWidth options property in the constructor**. Yes, even if setting the maximum width was not what you wanted to do.

Longer story:
Migrating a v2 map to v3, I saw exactly the problem described. Windows varied in width and height, and some had vertical scrollbars and some didn't. Some had <br /> embedded in the data, but at least one with that sized OK.

I didn't think the InfoWindowsOptions.maxWidth property was relevant, since I didn't care to *constrain* the width... but by setting it with the InfoWindow constructor, I got what I wanted, and the windows now autosize (vertically) and show the full content without a vertical scrollbar. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but it works!

See: http://fortboise.org/maps/sailing-spots.html

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to set `maxWidth` to a percentage, google maps will recognise a float as a percentage of the parent, and convert it to the pixel-equivalent: declare `{"maxWidth":0.25}`, parent element is 1000px wide, InfoWindow will have a `width: 250px`. I don't think it's possible to force InfoWindow's width to remain a percentage (the value of `maxWidth` must be a number, so `{"maxWidth":"25%"}` will not work and `{"maxWidth":25%}` is treated a 25 modulus undefined and triggers a syntax error).

Comment: Interesting. The current Google documentation says the google.maps.InfoWindowOptions.maxWidth property is "a number", and we have inferred units of pixels. There's no reason why the parser couldn't also accept a decimal number and interpret it as a fraction... and that be left as an undocumented "feature." Except maybe good sense.

Comment: Ok, +1 for working great, but why do I always end up on that sail page when researching gMap functionality.

Comment: After a bit of poking around the divitis that is googlemaps, it is not possible for the infowindow's width to remain a percent because of where infowindow actually sits in the DOM. Also, `{"maxWidth":0.25}` appears to be a bit flaky (some percentages work, others don't), so use with caution.

Comment: I have a vertically narrow map, and maxWidth makes no difference for me :( I've had to set the height in the CSS. Would be nice if I could specify a maximum, but Google won't let me!

Comment: **This may have worked in 2010, but does not help as of 2014.**

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that a not-quite-sensible workaround wasn't persistent. Looking at my sailing spots map again, I noticed ONE of the info windows got a scroll bar, and that it wasn't one with most content. I see that LONGER or SHORTER text in one of the components that are rolled into the infowindow will make the scrollbar go away. Quirky, huh? Try ADDING characters to the contents maybe?!

Comment: @Simon new year, new problems... any solutions on the fix this time round?

Comment: I have had more success with the poup window size in version 3.19 (released 15 Feb 2015) of Google maps .  Perhaps try that?

Answer (score 25):

You should give the content to InfoWindow from jQuery object.

```
var $infoWindowContent = $("<div class='infowin-content'>Content goes here</div>");
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent($infoWindowContent[0]);
```

Comment: Ok this is working just fine, many thanks ... Now I wanna know why :)

Comment: This is among the weirdest fixes I have ever seen. None of the other hacks for this question worked for me except this. Unbelievable.

Comment: For some reason, the maps API appears not to put `overflow: auto` on the InfoWindow DIV when you pass in DOM nodes instead of a string.  This solves the problem if the content is only out by 1-2px.  Unfortunately this means that longer content actually *hangs out* of the InfoWindow instead of having scrollbars added.

Comment: While this does work, it's pretty nasty to ask people to include jQuery on the page simply so `infoWindow's` display correct. The complete answer as to why this works is listed in my answer - `jQuery` creates a detached DOM tree which forces the content to be correctly rendered and it's size accurately determined before google attempts to place the `infoWindow` on the map

Answer (score 22):

**EDITED (to standout): Trust me, out of the hundred other answers to this question, this is the only correct one that also explains WHY it's happening**

Ok, so I know this thread is old, and has a thousand answers, but **none of them is correct** and I feel the need to post the correct answer.

Firstly, you **do not** ever need to specify `width's` or `height's` on anything in order to get your infoWindow to display without scrollbars, although sometimes you may accidentally get it working by doing this (but it's will eventually fail).

Second, Google Maps API `infoWindow's` **do not** have a scrolling bug, it's just very difficult to find the correct information on how they work. Well, here it is:

When you tell the Google Maps API to open in infoWindow like this:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({...});
....
infoWindow.setContent('<h1>Hello!</h1><p>And welcome to my infoWindow!</p>');
infoWindow.open(map);
```

For all intents and purposes, google maps temporarily places a `div` at the end of your page (**actually it creates a `detached DOM tree` - but it's conceptually easier to understand if I say you imagine a `div` being places at the end of your page**) with the HTML content that you specified. It then measures that div (which means that, in this example, whatever CSS rules in my document apply to `h1` and `p` tags will be applied to it) to get it's `width` and `height`. Google then takes that `div`, assigns the measurements to it that it got when it was appended to your page, and places it on the map at the location you specified.

Here's where the problem happens for a lot of people - they may have HTML that looks like this:

```
<body>
 <div id="map-canvas"><!-- google map goes here --></div>
</body>
```

and, for whatever reason, CSS that looks like this:

```
h1 { font-size: 18px; }
#map-canvas h1 { font-size: 32px; }
```

Can you see the problem? When the API tries to take the measurements for your `infoWindow` (immediately before displaying it), the `h1` part of the content will have a size of `18px` (because the temporary "measuring div" is appended to the body), but when the API actually places the `infoWindow` on the map, the `#map-canvas h1` selector will take precedence causing the font size to be much different than what it was when the API measured the size of the `infoWindow` and in this circumstance you will ***always*** get scrollbars.

There may be more slightly different nuances for the specific reason why you have scrollbars in your `infoWindow`, but the reason behind it is because of this:

> The same CSS rules must apply to the content inside your `infoWindow`
>   regardless of where the actual HTML element appears in the markup. If
>   they do not, then you will be **guaranteed** to get scrollbars in your
>   infoWindow

So what I always do, is something like this:

```
infoWindow.setContent('<div class="info-window-content">...your content here...</div>');
```

and in my CSS:

```
.info-window-content { ... }
.info-window-content h1 { .... }
.info-window-content p { ... }
etc...
```

So no matter where the API appends it's measurement `div` - before the closing `body` or inside a `#map-canvas`, the CSS rules applied to it will always be the same.

**EDIT RE: Font Families**

Google seems to be actively working on the font loading issue (described below) and functionality has changed very recently so you may or may not see the Roboto font load when your `infoWindow` opens the first time, depending on the version of the API you are using. There is an open bug report (even though in the [changelog](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog) this bug report was already marked as fixed) that illustrates that google is still having difficulty with this problem.

**ONE MORE THING: WATCH YOUR FONT FAMILIES!!!**

In the latest incarnation of the API, google tried to be clever and wrap it's infoWindow content in something that could be targeted with a CSS selector - `.gm-style-iw`. For people that didn't understand the rules that I explained above, this didn't really help, and in some cases made it even worse. Scrollbars would almost always appear the first time an `infoWindow` was opened, but if you opened any `infoWindow` again, even with the **exact same content** the scrollbars would be gone. Seriously, if you weren't confused before this would make you lose your mind. Here's what was happening:

If you look at the styles that google loads on the page when it's API loads, you'll be able to see this:

```
.gm-style {
     font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif
 ...
}
```

Ok, so Google wanted to make it's maps a bit more consistent by always making them use the `Roboto` font-family. The problem is, for the majority of people, the before you opened an `infoWindow`, the browser hadn't yet downloaded the `Roboto` font (because nothing else on your page used it so the browser is smart enough to know that it doesn't need to download this font). Downloading this font isn't instantaneous, even though it is very fast. The first time you open an `infoWindow` and the API appends the `div` with your `infoWindow` content to the body to take it's measurements, it starts downloading the `Roboto` font, but your `infoWindow's` measurements are taken and the window is placed on the map before `Roboto` finishes downloading. The result, quite often, was an `infoWindow` whose measurements were taken when it's content was rendered using `Arial` or a `sans-serif` font, but when it was displayed on the map (and `Roboto` had finished downloading) it's content was being displayed in a font that was a different size - and voila - scrollbars appear the first time you open the `infoWindow`. Open the exact same `infoWindow` a second time - at which point the `Roboto` has been downloaded and will be used when the API is taking it's measurements of `infoWindow` content and you won't see any scrollbars.

Comment: Some great detail there Adam, and yes I discovered similar things to you.  However, [the bug as reported to Google](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5713) *does* actually appear to still occur even with system fonts and no descendent CSS selectors.  See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/qgbv0zdm/) (has a scrollbar in Chrome 40 Win).

Comment: @Simon - you are correct, the link you submitted is a bug (extremely edge case, but a bug nonetheless). I would imagine that >98% of the time, when people report their infoWindows have and they don't know why - it's because of the issues addressed in this answer.

Comment: Adam. Thanks so much for providing this answer. You saved me a bunch of unnecessary hacking!

Answer (score 21):

```
.gm-style-iw{
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

it works for me

Comment: This is not a great solution as any content that *is* larger than the info window will be cut off and hidden.

Comment: Not perfect for varying length content, but my content is pretty much the same for each pointer applying a width !important and height !important was enough of a solution for me!

Answer (score 13):

I tried each one of the answers listed.  None worked for me.
This finally fixed it PERMANENTLY.
The code I inherited had a `DIV` wrapper around all the `<h#>` and `<p>` entries.  I simply forced some "style" in the same DIV, taking into account a desired max width, threw in the line height change just in case (someone else's fix) and my own `white-space: nowrap`, which then made the auto overflow make the correct adjustments.  No scroll bar, no truncation and no problems!

```
html = '<div class="map-overlay" style="max-width: 400px;
                                        line-height: normal;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        overflow: auto;
                                       ">';
```

Comment: This one!  Worked my way down through all the answers without success until I got here.  In my case, it was the `white-space: nowrap` that had the magic - the other styles were unnecessary.  Cheers!

Comment: This does indeed seem to work, however, some of the infowindows had to be clicked more than once though...  my final solution was to combine this answer with [Concept211](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17616524/594235)'s by adding `font-family: sans-serif !important; font-weight: normal !important;` to the CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately if you have any long lines, the lines will get cut off instead of wrapping.  Not an ideal solution unless you *know* all your lines are short.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old thread, but I just encountered the same problem.  I had `<h2>` and `<p>` elements in the InfoWindow, and these both had bottom margins.  I removed the margins, and InfoWindow sized correctly.  None of the other suggested fixes worked.  I suspect that the InfoWindow size calculation doesn't take the margins into account.

Comment: I was having this issue and none of the other fixes worked, but this one did. Thanks :)

Comment: This applies to all margins used inside the window.

Comment: I still had problems, but just wrapped everything in
`<div style='overflow:hidden;'></div>`
Looks good now.

Answer (score 10):

Going to add my answer to the list, since NONE of these fixed my problem. I ended up wrapping my content in a div, giving that div a class, and specifying the `min-width` on the div, AND specifying the `maxWidth` on the infoWindow, AND they both needed to be the same size, otherwise either the width or the height would be overflowing on boxes with just the wrong amount of content.

Javascript:

```
// Set up the content for the info box
var content = "<div class='infowindow-content'>" + content + "</div>";

// create a map info box
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 350,
    content: content
});
```

CSS:

```
div.infowindow-content {
    min-width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Setting a `min-width` on the content was the only thing that worked for me too. Didn't have to set the `maxWidth` on the infoWindow though.

Comment: @MarkParnell = make sure to test thoroughly. I was running into issues when i had more than a certain amount of text at a given width! If you know what the content is going to be, then no biggie :)

Comment: Thank you so much.. this helped me too. In mobile view i gave maxWidth: 350. still it was taking some random value. with the help of min-width it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried all of these solutions and none worked.  After some trial and error I figured it out.

```
<style type="text/css">
#map_canvas {
    line-height:normal;
}
</style>
```

Set line-height:normal for the map canvas div.

Comment: yes! line height is what fixed it for me too. nothing else worked. specifically, i had line height set in my stylesheet to { line-height: 1.3; }. i changed it to { line-height: 1.3em } and it resolved the issue.

Comment: or alternately you can just set the line height of the map container div to normal as indicated above.

Comment: There is no `#map_canvas` in Google Maps v3 that I can see.  This must be from the old v2.

Comment: @Simon `#map_canvas` is the div you use for the map. It can be whatever name you want it to be.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.  This fiddle still displays a scrollbar in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/dckxp62o/

Answer (score 8):

It appears that the issue is with the Roboto webfont.

The infowindow is rendered with inline width and height properties based on the content provided. However, it is not calculated with the webfont already rendered/loaded. Once the font is rendered AFTER the entire map is printed to the screen, then it causes the scrollbars to appear due to the "overflow:auto" properties inline inside the window's DIVs.

The solution I found to work is to wrap the content in a DIV and then apply CSS to override the webfont:

```
.gmap_infowin {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

<div class="gmap_infowin">Your info window content here.</div>
```

Comment: this solution works for me. Also hiding scroll works:
.gm-style-iw{ overflow: hidden !important;}
but this will hide part of content in infoWindow

Comment: +1 yes!  But I combined this answer with [user2656824](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18677331/594235)'s.

Comment: +1 because it is the only answer that seems to finally acknowledge the fact that this is due to the Roboto font issues. i wouldn't be surprised if other fonts rendered wrongly as well. the problem is that .gm-style-iw calculates a tiny bit lesser height than necessary, probably because of the float rounding. the really only reasonable option is unfortunate  .gm-style-iw{overflow: hidden !important;}. of course, this becomes useless once you really do have to scroll though

Comment: The Roboto font *does* appear to trigger this issue *sometimes*, but it happens also with Arial and default fonts.  If you look at this fiddle with your suggested fix in Chrome 38 on Windows it still has a nasty scrollbar:  http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/dckxp62o/2/

Answer (score 5):

**Funny enough, while the following code will correct the WIDTH scroll bar:**

```
.gm-style-iw
{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 1.35;

}
```

**It took this to correct the HEIGHT scroll bar:**

```
    .gm-style-iw div
    {
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Adding white-space: nowrap; to either style might correct the spacing issue that seems to linger when the scroll bars are removed. Great point Nathan.

Comment: I think my problem was caused by an h4 tag wrapping.  When I added your suggestion it removed the scroll bars but there was a tiny  bit off the bottom of the window.  When I added white-space: nowrap; to the h4 it all got better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.
Put a `div` in the `setContent`

```
sh_map.infoWindow.setContent([
  '<div id=\"mydiv\">',
  'Your content goes here',
].join(''));
```

Then add this CSS to your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
#map-canvas {
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#mydiv {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
 font-size: 10px;
 border-top-width: 0px;
 border-right-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
 border-left-width: 0px;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 word-spacing: normal;
}
</style>
```

For example, see http://www.student-homes-northampton.co.uk; click the links under the house pics to display the Google map.

Comment: thanks, it wasn't until i set my font to comic-sans that this started working.

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem completely:

```
.gm-style-iw {
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest answer that worked for me. Instead of auto height, I added a minimum height instead.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with IE and tried many of the fixes detailed in these responses, but was unable to remove the vertical scrollbars in IE reliably.

What worked best for me was to switch to fixed font sizes inside the infowindow -- 'px'... I was using ems.  By fixing the font size I no longer needed to explicitly declare the infowindow width or height and the scrollbars were gone for good.

Comment: It helps sometimes, but doesn't reliably fix the problem.  If you view this fiddle in Chrome 38 on Windows it still has an ugly scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/dckxp62o/3/

Answer (score 2):

Also important is height of the map container. If to small infoWindow always will be on 80px height. Otherwise `maxWidth` and `#innerDiv` fix works like a charm.

Comment: Exactly, I dont think is any fixed size, but the point is that if the map is not big enough (height in this case) then the infowindow won't resize to wrap our content. 

Try making the map bigger and check again

Comment: THIS is the most correct answer here. Too small a map is typically the cause of the infowindow sizing issues. If you want to test the theory out just inspect the map container and increase the width and height.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still issues even with a suitably large map.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, try adding the content after the window has been opened.  This should force it to resize.

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
infoWindow.open(map, marker)
infoWindow.setContent(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the domready event and reopen the info window and show the hidden content after the domready event fires twice to ensure all of the dom elements have been loaded.

```
// map is created using google.maps.Map() 
// marker is created using google.maps.Marker()
// set the css for the content div .infowin-content { visibility: hidden; } 

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();    
infowindow.setContent("<div class='infowin-content'>Content goes here</div>");
infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
infowindow.set("isdomready", false);
infowindow.open(map);   

// On Dom Ready
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    if (infowindow.get("isdomready")) {
        // show the infowindow by setting css 
        jQuery('.infowin-content').css('visibility', 'visible');               
    }
    else {
        // trigger a domready event again.
        google.maps.event.trigger(infowindow, 'content_changed');
        infowindow.set("isdomready", true);
    }
}
```

I tried just doing a setTimeout(/* show infowin callback */, 100), but sometimes that didn't work still if the content (ie: images) took too long to load.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, particularly noticeable when my `<h2>` element wrapped to a second line.

I applied a class to a `<div>` in the infoWindow, and changed the fonts to a generic system font (in my case, Helvetica) versus an @font-face web font which it had been using. Issue solved.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a reliable fix.  The issue has been known to occur with Arial and other standard fonts too.

Answer (score 0):

```
//infowindow.setContent(response);    
var infowindowopts = { 
    maxWidth: 274, 
    content: response
};
infowindow.setOptions(infowindowopts);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to add a listener (using addListenerOnce) to check if the infoWindow has been added to the DOM, then opening the infoWindow again (no need to close it).

```
// map, marker and infoWindow code, we'll call them 
// myMap, myMarker and myInfoWindow

myInfoWindow.open(myMap, myMarker);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(myInfoWindow, 'domready', function(){
                myInfoWindow.open(myMap, myMarker);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-height` to your infoWindow class element.

That will resolve the issue if your infoWindows are all the same size.

If not, add this line of jQuery to your click function for the infoWindow:

```
//remove overflow scrollbars
$('#myDiv').parent().css('overflow','');
```

Comment: You're on the right track.  The min-height of infoWindow won't help you, as that DIV is contained within out DIV that's overflowing.  So setting a min-height will make it scroll every time.

Comment: Looking at the structure of the DOM, it's actually the GRANDPARENT of the infoWindow class that needs the overflow removed on.    My code looks something like:  infoCallBack = function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) {
        return function () { /* code for displaying window goes here, then my overflow fix next */  setTimeout(function() { $('.infowindow').parent().parent().css('overflow',''); },25);  }  }  Which basically triggers the fix of the infoWindow after 25ms, enough time for it to render.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt get it to work in any way shape or form, I was including 3 divs into the box. I wrapped them in an outer div, with widths and heights all set correctly, and nothing worked.

In the end I fixed it by setting the div as absolute top left, and then before the div, I set two images, one 300px wide and 1px high, one 120px high and 1px wide, of a transparent gif.

It scaled properly then!

Its ugly but it works.

You could also do one image and set a zindex I expect, or even just one image if your window has no interaction, but this was containing a form, so, that wasn't an option...

Answer (score 0):

I think that this behavior is because of some css styling in an outer container, I had the same problem but I solved it using an inner div an adding some padding to it, I know it's weird but it solved the problem

```
<div id="fix_height">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Something</p>
</div>
```

And in my style.css

```
div#fix_height{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an inline element (an a tag) directly inside of the `div` with `style="overflow:auto"[...` wrapped that in a `p` tag and fixed it.

Looks like any inline element that is not nested in a block element directly inside of the infowindow will cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my CSS did the trick for me:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: That will remove the wrapping on long lines.  I don't think that's a suitable solution for many people.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize all the solutions that worked for me in all browsers:

- Don't use margins inside the infowindow, only padding.
- Set a max-width for the infowindow:

  `this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 200
  });`
- Wrap the contents of the infowindow with

  `<div style="overflow:hidden;line-height:1.35;min-width:200px;">*CONTENT*</div>`

  (change the min-width for the value you set on the infowindow maxWidth)

I have tested it and it worked on every browser, and I had over 400 markers...

Comment: This sets a fixed width to the InfoWindow (no longer fluid), which is one solution, but not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I know that lots of other people have found solutions that worked for their particular case, but since none of them worked for *my* particular case, I thought this might be helpful to someone else.

Some details:

I'm using google maps API v3 on a project where inline CSS is something we really, really want to avoid. My infowindows were working for everything except for IE11, where the width was not calculated correctly. This resulted in div overflows, which triggered scrollbars.

I had to do three things:

1. Remove all display: inline-block style rules from anything inside of the infowindow content (I replaced with display: block) - I got the idea to try this from a thread (which I can't find anymore) where someone was having the same problem with IE6.
2. Pass the content as a DOM node instead of as a string. I am using jQuery, so I could do this by replacing: `infowindow.setContent(infoWindowDiv.html());` with `infowindow.setContent($(infoWindowDiv.html())[0]);`
   This turned out to be easiest for me, but there are lots of other ways to get the same result.
3. Use the "setMaxWidth" hack - set the MaxWidth option **in the constructor** - setting the option later doesn't work. If you don't really want a max width, just set it to a very large number.

I don't know why these worked, and I'm not sure if a subset of them would work. I know that none of them work for all of my use cases individually, and that 2 + 3 doesn't work. I didn't have time to test 1 + 2 or 1 + 3.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't acceptable for me to hard code the width and height of the info window, or to set `white-space: nowrap`, the `maxWidth` solution didn't help me and everything else either didn't work or was otherwise inappropriate for my use case.

My solution was to set the content, open the window and then when the `domready` event is fired, set the `height` CSS property on the content to whatever the height is, and then force Google Maps to resize the InfoWindow accordingly.

`infoWindow` is the InfoWindow object, `$infoWindowContents` is a Jquery object of the contents I want to put in there, `map` is my Map object. `marker` is a marker which was clicked.

```
infoWindow.setContent($infoWindowContents.get(0));

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
  // Stop listening, otherwise the listeners stack up if the window is opened again
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);

  // Set the height on the container to however tall the browser is currently rendering it
  $infoWindowContents.height($infoWindowContents.height());

  // Force Google Maps to recalculate the InfoWindow height
  infoWindow.setContent($infoWindowContents.get(0));
});

infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

(I posted the same solution over on a similar question [How do I get a google-maps InfoWindow to resize to fit the content that is placed inside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294388/how-do-i-get-a-google-maps-infowindow-to-resize-to-fit-the-content-that-is-place/24707034))

Answer (score 0):

After losing time and reading for a while, I just wanted something simple, this css worked for my requirements.

```
.gm-style-iw > div { overflow: hidden !important; }
```

Also is not an instant solution but starring/commenting on the issue might make them fix it, as they believe it is fixed:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5713

Comment: This cuts content off in some cases. :-(  In this fiddle on Chrome 38 on Windows the "dddd" is cut off completely: http://jsfiddle.net/simoneast/dckxp62o/4/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the one that did the trick for me:

```
.gm-style-iw>div {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Only setting `overflow: visible` on `.gm-style-iw` actually made the problem worse! I noticed in the Chrome developer tools inspector that there are two divs inside the `.gm-style-iw` element, both which have `overflow: auto` set by default.

I'm displaying quite a lot of HTML-formatted text in my InfoWindows, that might be why the other solutions didn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of **mid-2014** there appears to be an **InfoWindow sizing bug in Google Maps v3** that affects multiple browsers.

It has been reported here:
**https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5713**
([and a demo JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/67nQF/7/))
*Please click the star on the issue above to vote for it to be fixed!*

From all my testing, it appears to be **related to element size rounding errors**, as it only occurs at some font-sizes.

### Bad workarounds:

Having toyed with most suggestions on this page, the following are **NOT good solutions**:

- `overflow: hidden` (can potentially cut off content)
- `white-space: nowrap` (can potentially cut off content)
- Passing a jQuery object or DOM nodes (content potentially overflows outside the InfoWindow)
- Setting the InfoWindow content after it is opened (on its own, does not help)
- Changing font away from Roboto (the issue can occur with any font)

One possible workaround is giving your InfoWindow a fixed width (such as those who've suggested setting max-width and min-width), however when you have lots of markers and the amount of content varies fluctuates, this is not ideal.  It's also bad for mobile/responsive designs.

### A reasonable workaround:

So until Google fix this, I've had to build a workaround. After about 12+ hours of testing and debugging I came up with the following:

This does *not* have the same drawbacks as other suggestions.

- Content should never be clipped (unless you have large images that exceed the width of the InfoWindow).
- Vertical scrollbars are added, but only when necessary.
- No content should overflow outside of the InfoWindow
- In most cases the InfoWindow is sized automatically to fit the content (not a fixed size)
- Should be suitable for mobiles and responsive layouts
- Margins, padding, fonts should all work OK

### Downsides:

- My version requires jQuery, but it could probably be reworked to be pure JS
- It creates 20px of padding on the right of the content to make room for the scrollbar in case it is needed.  You could skip this if you prefer, or do some more checking to only add padding when necessary.
- It's rather hacky, but without editing Google's javascript, it's possibly the only way.

## [View Code on Github](https://gist.github.com/SimonEast/16b5bf3d56c0e5035b31)

Please submit improvements and corrections as you find them.

Answer (score -1):

add to css

```
.gm-style-iw{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

info window text:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height:150px;">
  here text of the info window
</div>
```

Comment: This will hide any information that is too big for the info window.

Answer (score -1):

I found that any setting of line-height within any of the elements inside the infoWindow content caused this issue. removing the line-height settings solved this for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still sometimes occurs with default line-heights.

Answer (score -1):

I tried most (if not all) answers alone from above but none worked in my case.
So i combined a couple of them trying to figure out the minimum i need.

And this combination worked for me:

```
div.infowindow {
    font-family: Courier;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Your milage may vary.  good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't really offer anything additional to other answers here, and is not a very reliable fix.  It will cause content to get cut off instead of wrapping and scrolling.