# Why is a scroll bar coming out in my maps infowindow in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//set location of san antonio 
var san_antonio = new google.maps.LatLng(29.4, -98.544);

//set infowindow
var infoWindow;

//object literal containing the properties
var options = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: san_antonio,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}

//create the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

//create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: san_antonio,
  map:map,
  title: "san antonio"
});


//add 'click' event listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){

//creates infowindow if it already doesn't exist
if (!infoWindow){
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

//create content for infowindow
var content = '<div id="information">'+'<img src="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1549555880/Screenshot.png"/>'+'</div>'

//set content of the infowindow. 
infoWindow.setContent(content);

//open infowindow on click of marker 
infoWindow.open(map,marker);

//ends the event listener
}); 


//ends the DOM loader
});
```

In chrome i get an unwanted scroll bar in the infowindow when it pops up. If you look at the bottom right corner you will notice that there is a little bit of distortion as well.

## In Chrome

[image: my infowindow rendering in chrome]

The infowindow looks great in Firefox. I was not having this problem last night when I was working on my desktop, so I am thinking that my chrome installation may be broken on my laptop. What do you think? Here is what it looks like in FireFox:

## In FireFox

[image: einfowindow rendering in firefox]

I tried doing `div#information{overflow:hidden}`, but nothing changed
I then tried doing  `div#information{overflow:hidden;height:500px;background-color:green;}`, and then the scroll bar just got longer.
This is telling me that the infowindow is acting as its own div and that the 'information' div's height is causing the infowindow's scroll bar to get larger.
[image]

---

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this css style:

```
div#information{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the scroll bar is still there. It seems like the scroll bar is not part of the 'information' div because as I change the height, the scroll bar gets longer. It seems like the infowindow is acting like a div that is being overflowed by the 'information' div.

Comment: i'll post some more so you can see what I mean.

Comment: read this please and try: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/css-stylizing-google-maps-infowindow.html

Comment: Yeah, I think my chrome browser is just messed up. I tried it on my desktop and it worked fine there. I also tried it in jsfiddle and it was rendering the way I wanted. Plus, nothing can really explain the distortion of the shadow and the bottom right corner.

Comment: great! I'm glad! Although just a cache problem After you add the css class!

Answer (score 4):

```
.gm-style-iw{ overflow: hidden !important;}
```

it works for me

Answer (score 2):

may be an issue with line-height. that's what was causing the error for me. see [Google Maps API v3: InfoWindow not sizing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly/11125793#answer-11125793) answer #11125793 (Nick).

Answer (score 2):

[This solution](http://www.canbike.ca/information-technology/2013/11/01/firefox-infowindow-scrollbar-fix-google-maps-api-v3.html) worked for me:

```
line-height:1.35;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```