# Google maps V3 infowindow doesn't size to image

Tags: html, google-maps, infowindow

I'm having some trouble getting my infowindow to have the size that I want. I'm trying to place a 15px x 15px image inside of the infowindow and have the infowindow size itself accordingly. However, it seems no matter what I do the infowindow is much much bigger than the image. Here's the code I am trying to put inside the infowindow:

```
<div style="width: 15px; height 15px">
  <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw/6/walk.png" width="15" height="15">
</div>
```

Then here's the code to make and display the window itself:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: window_text,
  position: GPS_coordinates,
  maxWidth: "15px"
});
infowindow.open(map);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a minimum size to the InfoWindow because of the graphics from which it's constructed. The minimum width is 247px, and setting `maxWidth` to anything less than this figure will cause the width to be 247px.

**References**
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/Dnew8W5Trjg
[How to size a Google Maps InfoWindow in Javascript (v3 API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142233/how-to-size-a-google-maps-infowindow-in-javascript-v3-api)

**Other resources**
You might try the *InfoBox* or the *InfoBubble* in the Utility library
http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries