# Google Map Infowindow not showing properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

The infowindow is not showing properly on my map when clicking on a marker. The website is here.

You'll also notice the map control isn't properly displayed either.

```
    var map;
    var locations = <?php print json_encode(di_get_locations()); ?>;
    var markers = []
    jQuery(function($){
        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.840639771473, 5.8587418730469),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

        for (var i=0; i < locations.length;i++) {
            makeMarker(locations[i]);
        }
        centerMap();

    });
    function makeMarker(location) {
        var markerOptions = {map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng)};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        markers.push(marker);
        var content = '';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
          { content: "test",
            size: new google.maps.Size(50,50),
            disableAutoPan : true
          });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
    function centerMap() {
      map.setCenter(markers[markers.length-1].getPosition());
    }
```

Note: I'm using Google Maps JS V3.

Comment: There's no longer a link to your website and so it's unclear what problem you're having. Your question as it stands is unlikely to help any users in future.

Comment: It may also be a similar problem to the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The issue is forced by this format inside style.css:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;/* <--the problem occurs here*/
}
```

Add this to the end of your style.css to apply the default-value for images inside the map:

```
#map_canvas img{max-width:none}
```

Comment: This solved it for me too. If anyone wants to know what it looks like, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl8ci.png

Comment: It was pretty obvious but it saves me a lof of time. Thanks mate.

Comment: OMG, thanks! In my case, zoom control was affected by displaying the mao inside Bootstrap Modal window....

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be you are using `img{ max-width: 100%; }` as universal.

Try this one in to your css

```
.gmnoprint img {
    max-width: none; 
}
```

Comment: Why posting the same thing as the accepted answer more than 1 year later ?

Comment: @0x1gene the reason why `img{max-width:100%}` will effect other css properties of the project. At the same time `.gmnoprint img:{max-width: none; }` is not gonna effect any properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento case google map zoom controls were not displaying because of conflict with PROTOTYPE library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with :

```
.gmnoprint img {
    max-height: none;  
}
```

instead of `max-width`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had tried most of internet answers but that are not useful (not working), I had added custom css and map zoom control are visible also enable marker click. [This answer also useful for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904379/map-zoom-controls-not-displaying-correctly)

```
    .gmnoprint{
        display: block !important
    }
    .gmnoprint.gm-bundled-control.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .gm-tilt {
        display: none;
    }
    .gm-iv-address{
        height: 56px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too tracked this down to a CSS issue.  In my case we had a library setting all div's to position:relative.  Setting back to initial popped our controls back in place.

```
.gm-style div {
    position:initial;
}
```