# Map zoom controls not displaying correctly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created a simple map using API3. However, the zoom controls on the top left look "Squashed" - a they are not displaying properly. The rest of the map is fine. The weird thing is that I have used the same method as for previous sites, where things work well.

Here's some code:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var marker;
var markersArray=[];
var html;   //to create urls
var directionsVisible = new Boolean();
directionsVisible = false;

function initialize() {     
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var orchards = new google.maps.LatLng(52.512805,-2.76007);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: orchards,
        panControl: false
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    addMarker(orchards);
}
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The issue should be because of universal `img { max-width: 100%; }`

**Try this one in to your css**

```
.gmnoprint img {
    max-width: none; 
}
```

Comment: Also you can check this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663375/google-map-infowindow-not-showing-properly/50679179#50679179

Answer (score 8):

Initially I face same problem, then later on I realize

> **google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);**

play very important role.

I added it and for me it works.

Checkout following code.

**CSS code**

```
<style>
       #divmap {
         height: 300px;
         width:100%;
         margin: 10px;
         padding: 10px;

       }
       .gm-style img { max-width: none; }
       .gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
```

**For JS**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>

<script>

      function initialize() {
       var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 5,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(21,78),
         panControl:true,
         zoomControl:true,
         mapTypeControl:true,
         scaleControl:true,
         streetViewControl:true,
         overviewMapControl:true,
         rotateControl:true
       }
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divmap"),
            mapOptions);
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**and final html**

```
<div id="divmap"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the Dreamweaver fluid grid feature your default set up should look like this:

```
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Try this:

```
object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; }
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}
```

just replace the code as it is.