# my kml layer is showing but its off to the left

Tags: javascript, google-maps, embed

Im trying to add my map to my website, so far ive gotten it to show my map but its offset to the left by a few km

work in progress so far with markers off to the left: http://www.decking.co.il/indexwip.html#

my google maps site with the markers in the right place: http://goo.gl/maps/atvDH

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script> <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.147711,34.972229);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 9,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
myOptions);
 var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=211701918214336350936.0004be32c642b750948e4', 
{preserveViewport:true});  
ctaLayer.setMap(map); 
}
```

please can somebody tell me what im doing wrong? ive been searching all day for a solution, am I mixing the wrong commands? Have I over complicated it somewhere? I've seen theres a way to simply embed into a webpage but I dont know how to make that embed appear inside the box thats provided for it in the template I'm using

Comment: It doesn't look "off to the left" to me.  It looks like you have a css conflict like that [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962398/google-maps-api-v3-tools-visual-distortions).

Comment: awesome, fixed thanks very much, last question... how do I say that you answered my question?

Comment: Added my comment as an "answer".  You can accept it to show that it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look "off to the left" to me. It looks like you have a css conflict like that [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962398/google-maps-api-v3-tools-visual-distortions).