# Google maps info window UI doesn't look as is should

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Map Infowindow not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663375/google-map-infowindow-not-showing-properly)

I am not really sure how to provide an example of working code for this as I am working on a secure project.

Here is a screenshot of the issue I am facing[image: Google map infowindow looks wack!]

I can also provide you with the code I am using to generate the map.

In the header:
`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

In the body:

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
              var addressID = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("addy_var_se");?>, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('city_var_se');?>, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('state_var_se');?>';
              setMapAddress( addressID );

              function setMapAddress( address ) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var markers = [];

                geocoder.geocode( { address : address }, function( results, status ) {
                  if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                    var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var options = {
                      zoom: 15,
                      center: latlng,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map_canvas' ), options );
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location, title: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('event_venue_se');?>',
                    });
                    /* Create Info Windows */         

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: " "
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                      infowindow.setContent('<h3>'+this.title+'</h3>'+addressID);
                      infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    }


                } );
              }



              </script>
```

What is happening is when a user clicks the marker i have placed the funky looking info window generates. I have worked with Gmaps before and never seen this. Maybe a problem with v2 vs. v3?

Any insight would be great! thank you :)

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue, or you have woodlice in your graphics card.

Comment: @Dr.Molle that did the trick, thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: **add** this into your css  `.gmnoprint img{max-width: none;}`

Comment: seems to be dublicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904379/google-map-zoom-controls-not-displaying-correctly/18723355#18723355