# Google maps Infowindow doesnt size as expected

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I just want to display a default info window with the content `The 123456789`.
So I am using the maps [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) from google, and changing the infowindow content. Simple as that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"><meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>html, body, #map-canvas {height: 100%;margin: 0px;padding: 0px}</style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {zoom: 4,center: myLatlng};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);                        
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'The 123456789'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head><body><div id="map-canvas"></div></body></html>
```

I am getting this in both Firefox and Chrome (expected `The 123456789`). Only in IE I have the desired result. The rest of the text is wrapped and in chrome the scrollbar is also visible.

[image]

Now, as per the documentation, the InfoWindow should be expanded to fit my text, which it does if the content is a bit longer than the one I am testing. Is this a google maps styling issue and how can I simply display that text without custom InfoWindows and without hackish css?

**edit**

Tested the abode code again. The first time the infowindo is shown its problematic, the following times it's displayed as it should.

Comment: Your code as posted works in Chrome for me.

Comment: @geocodezip The first time I click it is displayed nearly as the image in the question, and subsequent clicks display the infowindow as it should.

Comment: That isn't what I saw in Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: The screenshot is using firefox. In chrome I also see a little vertical scrollbar in the left of the close button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to global `img` styling. To revert it I just added

```
.gm-style img { max-width: none; }
```

Kudos to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18723355/245495).

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and seems to be correct.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1bgvg74chb3hzt/Screenshot%202015-01-10%2017.53.36.png?dl=0

One thing you can do is, rather than create the infowindow full of content, you may wanna create the instance and, onclick set the content.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.setContent('something');
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
 });
```

Comment: I've tried this in my real issue and didn't help. The first time the infoWindow has the correct size. If I close and reopen it, it is like this. I always set content before show. In which browser you got that result using the code from my question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a listener to the infowindow 'domready' event (using addListenerOnce), close infowindow, then reopen it.

proof of concept code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'The 123456789'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow,'domready',function() {
      infowindow.close();
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I can replicate the issue using firefox. It seems resolved in Chrome. Just hit Ctrl+F5. The first time you click the marker it doesn't display correctly. Subsequent clicks work well.

Comment: The code snippet works for me in both Chrome (39.0.2171.95 m) and Firefox (34.0.5) [Ctrl+F5 & "Run code snippet"]

Answer (score 0):

You should put the text in a '<div>' tag with style or class that has style attributes

```
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: '<div style="width: 10em;">The 123456789</div>'
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
style="word-wrap:nospace"
```

as an attribute of your content

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<p style="word-wrap:nospace">'+The 123456789+'</p>'
});
```