# Wordpress theme breaks google maps, causing inset to appear

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-maps

When I put my google maps into a wordpress theme based on Genesis (http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis) it causes this weird inset window to appear.  I am using google maps javascript api v3

[image: broken google maps]

I think the theme has some strange css rule that is causing the problem.  I've tried the fixes in the answers here [Google Map broken in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223503/google-map-broken-in-wordpress)
Setting

```
#mapcanvas img{
  max-width: none;
}
```

or setting max-width to inherit.

No luck with either one of those.

The inset is a div which has an inline styled width and height of 256.

I tried triggering a map resize

google.maps.event.trigger(themap, "resize");

No change.

Is there a simple way to identify the css files that are affecting the google map canvas?

It works fine if I put all the code outside of wordpress:

[image: working map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the google console to look where the problems comes from.

Just open it and inspect the div, you should see something like this on the right :

[image: google inspector css]

All the CSS rules which affect the select element appears here, and the concerned file and line is show (here custom.css). It's the better way to find the problem :)