# Google Map InfoWindow displays scroll bars in Google Chrome

Tags: google-maps

For some reason InfoWindow is displaying scroll bars along with the content, I tried to have custom width and height to InfoWindow but it is not showing up. 
I tried the solution from here 
[Google Map Infowindow not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663375/google-map-infowindow-not-showing-properly)

Please refer following link
http://server.ashoresystems.com/~contacth/index.php?option=com_business&view=categoryresult&catid=2

- Click on 1 (has scroll bars)
- Click on 3 (even disturbed)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Very similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](http://www.canbike.ca/information-technology/2013/11/01/firefox-infowindow-scrollbar-fix-google-maps-api-v3.html).

I made this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veaz/7Zm8w/), displaying the bug and a workaround.

If you do not want to visit external links, here is the workaround description:

Add a wrapping div to your info window content:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div class="scrollFix">'+infoWindowContent+'</div>',
    [...]
}).open(map);
```

And use CSS definitions to avoid scrollbars:

```
.scrollFix {
    line-height: 1.35;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot !! just line-height got it fixed, did you need the other two lines?

Comment: Thanks it worked like magic! I understand `white-space: no-wrap;`, but how do `line-height` and `overflow` suppress scrollbars?

Comment: I can't remember why I needed them. I had various content in these InfoWindows like addresses and links. Maybe they didn't fit without the other two lines. Well, leave them out as long as you don't need them.

Comment: I have tried with infowindow=`"<div class='info_content'><h3>$each_facility[facility_name]</h3></div>"`. But it not works with this style. SO I replace `<h3>` with `<b>`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit

Is the workaround still required? My old JSfiddle does not show the bug anymore. Can you create a fiddle which shows the bug so we can discuss a fix?

Comment: @PhilippGächter I see the bug in an android app that uses javascript, but not in the web version. No idea why.

Answer (score 5):

To hide the scrollbars, give your content a high z-index stack order, eg.:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div style="z-index:99999">Message appears here</div>',
});
```

Or, add the following style:

```
.gm-style-iw {
    overflow:hidden!important;
    height:55px!important; //for 3 lines of text in the InfoWindow
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the height, jsut target the info window and any child divs e.g. `.gm-style-iw, .gm-style-iw div {
    overflow:hidden!important;
}`

Comment: Only it works for me. Other solutions are rubbish. So I have voted it.  Thank you

Comment: the .gm-style-iw selector was very useful. Google maps stripped all attributes, including class='scrollFix' so that didn't work for me. I ended up with this: 

`.gm-style-iw div * {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 1.35em;
}`
That's just to override `style='overflow:auto'` that's added by google maps. Now I only get scrollbars if the infoWindow can't get any higher. Try `.gm-style-iw div` (without *) to remove all scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps adds `style="overflow: auto;"` to the content root element and removes all other attributes, including your `style=...` or `class="scrollFix"`. You can override `overflow: auto`like this:

`.gm-style-iw div * {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    line-height: 1.35em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I  have an extension that changes the appearance of my scrollbars. That is why the ugly scrollbars appear on Google API info window boxes.

To get rid of the scrollbars and to have a good amount of padding, I just appended the following to my scrollbar appearance code:

```
div.gm-style-iw.gm-style-iw-c {
  padding-right: 12px !important;
  padding-bottom: 12px !important;
}

div.gm-style-iw.gm-style-iw-c div.gm-style-iw-d {
  overflow: unset !important;
}
```

You could probably just add that to your site too, to make it a fix for all your users.