# Google Maps controls not showing in Wordpress plugin

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wordpress

We are developing a Wordpress plugin, that shows a Google Map with placemarks, that you define on Friendsofplaces.com. Here is an example: http://agalod.com/wordpress/?page_id=23

Only, the Google Maps controls are messed up, respectively not showing at all. The first thing to presume is CSS-conflict. In Chrome and Firefox, I disabled all styles not coming from Google, for the controls, but no difference.

Comment: You might want to consider posting a code-sample or fiddle that demonstrates the issue so that others can replicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map Infowindow not showing properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663375/google-map-infowindow-not-showing-properly)

Comment: http://agalod.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css?ver=2013-07-18 Line: 654

Comment: Dr. Molle, thanks, inserting *"<style> #fop-map img{max-width:none} </style>"* to the plugin-html made it.