# Why Google Map infowindow has a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a google map in my website and for some reason when the page initially load there is a scroll bar for the info window but after clicking on other marker and coming back to the initially marker that was showing the info window, there is no scroll bar.

Here is a screenshot when the page loads:

[image]

After I click on the other markers with the "H" icon and come back to the building icon, the scroll bar is gone:

[image]

Here is my HTML/CSS/JQuery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Map Location</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var infowindow = null;
var firstOne = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
        initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(41.04356, -73.784445);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: centerMap,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    setMarkers(map, sites);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading...", maxWidth: 350
    });
    infowindow.setContent(firstOne.html);
    infowindow.open(map, firstOne);
    //var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    //bikeLayer.setMap(map);
}

var sites = [
    ['Administrative Office', 41.0237, -73.701239, 1, '<span class=ttl><b> Administrative Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>0 Westchester Avenue<br>Purchase, NY 10577<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.963.0700</span>'],
    ['Purchase Office', 41.005615, -73.69566551, 2, '<span class=ttl><b>Purchase Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>3 Westchester Avenue<br>Purchase, NY 10577<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.533.4570</span>'],
    ['Rye Office', 40.9756737, -73.65614, 3, '<span class=ttl><b>Rye Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>45 Road<br>Rye, NY 10580<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.845.8822</span>'],
    ['Scarsdale Office', 40.973478, -73.8433, 4, '<span class=ttl><b>Scarsdale Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>6 White Plains Road, Suite 270<br>Scarsdale, NY 10583<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.213.7670</span>'],
    ['White Plains Office', 41.04579, -73.7464, 5, '<span class=ttl><b>White Plains Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>5 Westchester Avenue (GPS Enter: West Harrison)<br>White Plains, NY 10604<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.672.0776</span>'],
    ['White Plains Office', 41.0563, -73.75618, 6, '<span class=ttl><b>White Plains Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>5 Davfgs Avenue<br>White Plains, NY 10605<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.541.2450</span>'],
    ['Yonkers Office', 40.9442, -73.8554, 6, '<span class=ttl><b>Yonkers Office</b></span><br><br><span class=sbj>5 Hill Blvd<br>Yonkers, NY 10710<br><img src="theImages/phone.png" width="12" height="12" /> 914.545.8022</span>']
];


function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4]
        });
        var contentString = "Some content";
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        if(!firstOne) {
            firstOne = marker;
            marker.setIcon('theImages/hq.png');
        }
        else {
            marker.setIcon('theImages/hicon.png');
        }
    }           
}
</script>
<style>
.ttl {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #049600;
    text-align: left;
}
.sbj {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1050px; height: 395px; line-height: normal ! important"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, there is no scroll bar. Once the page fully loads, the scroll bar shows up.
How do I fix the scroll bar issue?

Comment: Very similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
#map_canvas > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.gm-style-iw {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: WORKED! Nice and simple. Thank you.

Comment: The real question is will this work in 6 months?  I think there are many more things to try from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly before settling with this solution.

Comment: Doesn't really help.  Content that's larger than the info window then just hangs outside and looks ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you're headed down the route of including a lot of information in your info windows, you might benefit more from pursuing the route of building your own custom info windows.  They have a great example up at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html .  I noticed you have jquery on your page as well, you might even benefit from looking at this post on how to integrate jQuery UI using Google's "InfoBox" extension - http://thewebstorebyg.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/google-maps-api-v3-tabs-inside-the-infowindow-using-infobox/

Comment: Lots of very good information. I will definitely look into it. Thanks.