# Google Maps InfoWindow shows an unwanted scrollbar (but only once)

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with my InfoWindows being shown incorrectly - it shows a scrollbar though it should not (but only the first time)!

On my page I have a lot of polyline routes and I am adding a marker/InfoWindow for each route. There are a lot of markers added (looped inside a Ajax call).

This is my definition of the InfoWindow (single instance before loop):

```
// Define an info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: "" } );
```

And this is inside my loop where I add markers:

```
// Set a marker on the last known position
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: lastLatLng,
    title: "My text",
    map: map,
    icon: iconCar
});

// Click on a marker to open an info window
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function() {
    infowindow.open(map,this);
    infowindow.setContent(this.title);
});
```

When I open up the map for the first time (in every new browser instance) I notice that the markup/display for the InfoWindow has a scrollbar - and I have not put it there nor should it even be there as the text is not that long.

**Wrong** (with scrollbar):

[image: InfoWindow with scrollbar - this is wrong]

The next time (and all the following) I click it, it shows up correctly without the scrollbar.

**Correct** (without scrollbar):

[image: InfoWindow without scrollbar - this is correct]

I don't have any CSS specified for Google Maps entries and even so it should be showing it wrong every time and not just the first time.

I have tried all tricks from this question, [Google Maps API v3: InfoWindow not sizing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554893/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-not-sizing-correctly), but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Please see this [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82nxB/) which shows my problem. I can reproduce the error every time if I close down all my (Chrome) browsers, go to the Fiddle and click on a route (as the first click). Then it will show the scrollbar the first time but only the first time.

Comment: It is scrollbar. It happens especially when infowindow is opened for the first time and is not fully expanded.

Comment: This problem occurs in Google's InfoWindow example window also. I found that there is a miscalculation for height in first openings(not every time), maybe you can report this as an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
div.gm-style-iw{
  overflow:hidden!important;
}
```

You're seeing the scrollbar because the default setting for the containing element with the scrollbar is `overflow:auto` and the content is exceeding the container's height.

You need to use the `!important` operator because the map styles are defined inline- and alternative would be to edit with Javascript, but this is likely overkill.

**[More on `!important` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)**

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.